# Bootstrap grid system wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

How can I do this?
[grid 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV83f.png)
instead of this?
[grid 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLusw.png)

Comment: Show what you have done first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the boxes can be divided into three columns you may try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bfrm0mth/2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="col-xs-12">frist item in column 1</span>
        <span class="col-xs-12">second item in column 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="col-xs-12">frist item in column 2</span>
        <span class="col-xs-12">second item in column 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="col-xs-12">frist item in column 3</span>
        <span class="col-xs-12">second item in column 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```